# The plugin generated xxx characters of unexpected output during activation

Tags: php, jquery, html, wordpress

I am creating WordPress plugin to display Total Twitter counter & Feed Subscriber. You can manage it via widget.

I am getting this error.

**The plugin generated 123 characters of unexpected output during activation. If you notice “headers already sent” messages, problems with syndication feeds or other issues, try deactivating or removing this plugin.**

```
<?php
/*
 * Plugin Name: Twitter & RSS Stats
 * Version: 1.0
 * Plugin URI: http://sss.com/
 * Description: Facebook, Twitter & RSS Social Stats widget <a href="http://jessealtman.com/2009/06/08/tutorial-wordpress-28-widget-api/">tutorial</a>.
 * Author: Ajay Patel
 * Author URI: http://sss.com/
 */

addHeaderCode();
 function addHeaderCode() {

            echo '<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="' . get_bloginfo('wpurl') . '/wp-content/plugins/TRR_Stats/css/style.css" />' . "\n";    
            }


 /*******************************/
 /*     Create table            */
 /********************************/
function my_plugin_create_table()
{
        // do NOT forget this global
    global $wpdb;

    // this if statement makes sure that the table doe not exist already
    if($wpdb->get_var("show tables like TRR_Stats") != 'TRR_Stats') 
    {
        $sql = "CREATE TABLE TRR_Stats (
        id mediumint(9) NOT NULL,
        rss_email tinytext NOT NULL,
        twitter tinytext NOT NULL,
        rss tinytext NOT NULL,
        UNIQUE KEY id (id)
        );";
        require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php');
        dbDelta($sql);
    }
}
// this hook will cause our creation function to run when the plugin is activated
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'my_plugin_create_table' );


class FTRWidget extends WP_Widget
{
    /**
    * Declares the FTRWidget class.
    *
    */
    function FTRWidget(){
        $widget_ops = array('classname' => 'widget_hello_world', 'description' => __( "Example widget demoing WordPress 2.8 widget API") );
        $control_ops = array('width' => 300, 'height' => 300);
        $this->WP_Widget('helloworld', __('Twitter & RSS Social Stats'), $widget_ops, $control_ops);
    }

    /**
    * Displays the Widget
    *
    */
    function widget($args, $instance){
        extract($args);
        $rss_email = empty($instance['rss_email']) ? 'webdesignergeeks' : $instance['rss_email'];
        $twitter = empty($instance['twitter']) ? 'webdesignergeek' : $instance['twitter'];
        $rss = empty($instance['rss']) ? 'webdesignergeeks' : $instance['rss'];


        # Featch Data from table
        global $wpdb;
        $item_info = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT * FROM TRR_Stats WHERE id=1;");
        $rss_email_f = $item_info->rss_email;

        $url = file_get_contents('https://feedburner.google.com/api/awareness/1.0/GetFeedData?uri=24thfloor');
        preg_match( '/circulation="(\d+)"/', $url, $matches );
        if ( $matches[1] )
        $rss_f = $matches[1] . " Subscribers";
        else
        echo "0";

        $twit = file_get_contents('http://twitter.com/users/show/'.$twitter.'.xml');
        preg_match( '/\<followers_count\>(\d+)\<\/followers_count\>/', $twit, $matches );
        if ( $matches[1] )
        $twitter_f = $matches[1] . " Followers";
        else
        $twitter_f = "0";



        echo '
            <div class="sidebarContainer" id="sidebarSubscribe">

            <a target="_blank" href="http://twitter.com/'.$twitter.'" class="subscribeSidebarBox" id="followTwitter">
                <span class="icon"><img src="'.get_bloginfo('url').'/wp-content/plugins/TRR_Stats/img/twitter.png" alt="Twitter" /></span>
                <span class="title">Follow Us on Twitter</span>
                <span class="count">'.$twitter_f.'+</span>
            </a>

            <a target="_blank" href="http://feeds.feedburner.com/'.$rss.'" class="subscribeSidebarBox" id="subscribeRSS">
                <span class="icon"><img src="'.get_bloginfo('url').'/wp-content/plugins/TRR_Stats/img/rss_feed.png" alt="RSS"/></span>
                <span class="title">Subscribe to our RSS feed</span>
                <span class="count">'.$rss_f.'+</span>
            </a>

            <a target="_blank" href="http://feedburner.google.com/fb/a/mailverify?uri='.$rss_email_f.'" class="subscribeSidebarBox" id="subscribeEmail">
                <span class="icon"><img src="'.get_bloginfo('url').'/wp-content/plugins/TRR_Stats/img/rss_email.png" alt="rss_email" /></span>

                <span class="title">Subscribe for updates via</span>
                <span class="count">EMAIL</span>
            </a>
        </div>';

        # After the widget
        echo $after_widget;
    }


    /**
    * Saves the widgets settings.
    *
    */
    function update($new_instance, $old_instance){
        $instance = $old_instance;
        $instance['rss_email'] = strip_tags(stripslashes($new_instance['rss_email']));
        $instance['twitter'] = strip_tags(stripslashes($new_instance['twitter']));
        $instance['rss'] = strip_tags(stripslashes($new_instance['rss']));

        global $wpdb;
            //Insert First time
            $wpdb->insert( 'TRR_Stats', array(
            'id'    => 1,
            'rss_email' => $instance['rss_email'], 
            'twitter' => $instance['twitter'],
            'rss' => $instance['rss']
            ) 
        );

        //Rest Update Data
        global $wpdb;
            $wpdb->update( 'TRR_Stats', 
            array( 
                'rss_email' => $instance['rss_email'], 
                'twitter' => $instance['twitter'],
                'rss' => $instance['rss']
            ),
            array(
                'id' => 1
            )

        );

        return $instance;
    }

    /**
    * Creates the edit form for the widget.
    *
    */
    function form($instance){
        //Defaults
        $instance = wp_parse_args( (array) $instance, array('rss_email'=>'', 'twitter'=>'engiguide', 'rss'=>'www.rss_email.com/engiguide') );

        $rss_email = htmlspecialchars($instance['rss_email']);
        $twitter = htmlspecialchars($instance['twitter']);
        $rss = htmlspecialchars($instance['rss']);

        # Output the options

        # Twitter
        echo '<p style="text-align:right;"><label for="' . $this->get_field_name('twitter') . '">' . ('Twitter:') . ' <input style="width: 200px;" id="' . $this->get_field_id('twitter') . '" name="' . $this->get_field_name('twitter') . '" type="text" value="' . $twitter . '" /></label></p>';
        echo '<p style="padding-left: 110;">i.e: webdesignergeeks</p>';
        # Rss
        echo '<p style="text-align:right;"><label for="' . $this->get_field_name('rss') . '">' . __('Rss:') . ' <input style="width: 200px;" id="' . $this->get_field_id('rss') . '" name="' . $this->get_field_name('rss') . '" type="text" value="' . $rss . '" /></label></p>';
        echo '<p style="padding-left: 110;">i.e: webdesignergeeks</p>';
        # Rss Email
        echo '<p style="text-align:right;"><label for="' . $this->get_field_name('rss_email') . '">' . ('Rss Email:') . ' <input style="width: 200px;" id="' . $this->get_field_id('rss_email') . '" name="' . $this->get_field_name('rss_email') . '" type="text" value="' . $rss_email . '" /></label></p>';
        echo '<p style="padding-left: 110;">i.e: webdesignergeeks</p>';

    }

}// END class

    /**
    * 
    * Calls 'widgets_init' action after the Hello World widget has been registered.
    */
    function TTRInit() {
    register_widget('FTRWidget');
    }   
    add_action('widgets_init', 'TTRInit');
?>
```

Comment: finally i have launched this plugin link : http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/twitter-rss-social-stats/

Comment: Disable your error reporting i.e define('WP_DEBUG', false);

Comment: @ManikThakur this is not generally a good idea. It is advised that  you resolve all errors and warnings before completing your plugin development.

Comment: Sometimes this happens because you have non-php code in your plugin file. In other words, you shouldn't `echo` anything directly and your `<php?` tag should start right at the beginning and `?>` end right at the end. My 2 character unexpected input was just because of a new line before `<php?`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Remove space from start of  tags. remove addHeaderCode(); from top and add this code add_action('wp_head', 'addHeaderCode'); to your file after addHeaderCode() function. its definitely resolve your problem.

Answer (score 13):

I got extra "xxx" white spaces after the final php closing tag. Removed it and the warning is gone. Those white spaces were the "unexpected output".

Comment: This is the right answer in my case. Remover any spaces or lines after the closing php tag like this one `?>` from every PHP file you have in your plugin.

Comment: this answer works only, lol...

Comment: It's not working for me.

Comment: Did you check all the files of the plugin?

Answer (score 5):

it was a UTF8 related issue. I converted it with Notepad++ in UTF8 but I had to conert it in "UTF8 (without BOM)".
Now I don't have any notice.

Answer (score 2):

You should try this:

1. remove white spaces
2. run function `plugin_error()`
3. in `wp_config.php` file set `wp_DEBUG true` , that will help you to see errors

This might help you.

Comment: I have downvoted your answer because of your reference to the plugin_error() function that is referenced nowhere.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you should be sending any output in `addHeaderCode()`, this occurs far too early. See [Actions Run During a Typical Request](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference).

Instead, try hooking to [wp_head](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_head) to add your stylesheet, which should be triggered between `<head>...</head>`.

Comment: i have solved it 70% the problem is speacing and comments make it buggy ,now i am syuck in to include css in this plugin

Comment: The problem is you're sending output to the browser before the rest of the page - add your stylesheet reference in the appropriate place with add_action('wp_head', 'addHeaderCode');

Comment: fin thanks for css help now apptox all r solved man thanks a lot

Comment: No worries =) It's also worth bearing in mind that you can also accidentally send output before headers if you've got spaces or blank lines before <?php (and that's sometimes difficult to spot!)

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the message with `__()` like `__("Hello, world!")` did the trick for me.

Comment: The `__()` and `_e()` functions only deal with translation.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove update() function without this function it will work fine and will do same thing you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with WooCommerce Smart Coupons plugin. I removed all extra new lines from plugin php files and saved them in "UTF8 (without BOM)" (as @Umaie Hamid mentioned). This fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed this by removing the spaces in the code using the "edit plugin" in the WP admin. I think when WP save the changes it also does all the necessary settings like saving the file as UTF-8.

Answer (score -1):

I Was getting same error just remove white spacing in your code.