# Why this Error occured while installing wordpress plugin?

Tags: php, wordpress

i have developed one wordpress-plugin and it users the post meta table after installation.
but before installation the error come.and i can not have view of the wordpress-plugin because of the error.

Error is,

```
The plugin generated 7267 characters of unexpected output during activation. 
If you notice “headers already sent” messages, problems with syndication 
feeds or other issues, try deactivating or removing this plugin.
```

this error comes when i install that plugin and plugin also not work because of an error.

Any one can help me for this.why this type of error occur?

Comment: may help this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7725615/the-plugin-generated-xxx-characters-of-unexpected-output-during-activation